# Tflite with Flutter - TensorBuffer to (Tensor)Image

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I did a segmentation with the tflite library for flutter and it works fine, I load the model, make an RGB [3, 224, 224] input and run it through the interpreter of the tflite_flutter_helper library.

But how to convert the output of my model, [1, 1, 224, 224] back to a TensorImage or an Image in general? When I run

```
TensorImage resultImage = TensorImage.fromTensorBuffer(tensorBuffer);
```

or

```
TensorImage resultImage = TensorImage(tensorBuffer.getDataType());
resultImage.loadTensorBuffer(tensorBuffer);
```

I get the error message:

```
The shape of a RGB image should be (h, w, c) or (1, h, w, c), and channels representing R, G, B in order. The provided image shape is [1, 224, 224, 1]
```

I tried solving it by rearranging my output to the shape of (1, h, w, c) like shown in the error to [1, 224, 224, 1], but I get the same result. Heres my full code:

```
ImageProcessor imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
    .add(ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR))
    .add(NormalizeOp(127.5, 127.5))
    .build();

SequentialProcessor<TensorBuffer> probabilityProcessor = TensorProcessorBuilder().add(DequantizeOp(0, 1 / 255)).build();

TensorImage tensorImage = TensorImage(TfLiteType.float32);
tensorImage.loadImage(img.Image.fromBytes(224, 224, image.readAsBytesSync()));
tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

TensorBuffer tensorBuffer;

try{
  Interpreter interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('models/enet.tflite');
  tensorBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape, interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).type);

  interpreter.run(tensorImage.buffer, tensorBuffer.getBuffer());

  tensorBuffer = probabilityProcessor.process(tensorBuffer);

  // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
  tensorBuffer.resize(List<int>.of([1, 224, 224, 1]));

  TensorImage resultImage = TensorImage(tensorBuffer.getDataType());
  resultImage.loadTensorBuffer(tensorBuffer);

}catch(e){
  print('Error loading model: ' + e.toString());
}
```

I furthermore tried reading in the buffer from the tensorBuffer directly into a Image of flutter via

```
Image result = Image.memory(tensorBuffer.getBuffer().asUint8List());
```

with an invalid imae data exception as a result.

**** EDIT ****
I also tried the ImageConversions class from tflite_flutter_helper with

```
img.Image resultImage = ImageConversions.convertGrayscaleTensorBufferToImage(tensorBuffer);
```

but still no success...

Answer (score 0):

```
Image tensorBufferToImage(TensorBuffer buffer, int w, int h) {
    List<int> floatList = buffer.getIntList();
    Uint8List uint8list =
        Uint8List.fromList(floatList.map((f) => f.toInt()).toList());

    int channels = 3;
    Image image = Image(w, h);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int r = uint8list[y * w * channels + x * channels];
        int g = uint8list[y * w * channels + x * channels + 1];
        int b = uint8list[y * w * channels + x * channels + 2];
        image.setPixel(x, y, getColor(r, g, b));
      }
    }
    return image;
  }
```

You can convert your buffer to List and from there try to populate the Image pixels